# PyTorch: batching from multiple datasets

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I have multiple datasets that I want to use in the training. I want each batch to be from one dataset but have batches from (possibly) all of the datasets in each epoch.

Merging the datasets into one simple `Dataset` object and using the default `Dataloader` leads to having samples from different datasets in one batch.

My own guess is to have a separate `Dataset` object for each dataset and override the Dataloader or the sampler, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to solve your problem is to have a single merged dataset with a single data loader, but have a custom [`BatchSampler`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.BatchSampler) that yields indices based on the different datasets inside the merged dataset.